# SPFx Application Customizer and SPFx WebPart Connection

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-extensions, applicationcustomizers

I know we can create connected SPFx webparts but is it possible to create the connection between SPFx application customizer and SPFx webpart?

The scenario is that we need to create application customizer (kind of welcome message and some options like search, switch, etc.) in the header of the page and on change event of the switch button, we need to show different view of the webpart (Grid/List view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately dynamic data is available only for web parts. That said, you could try to use a library component to see if you could implement a central location for storing state and triggering events. For more information about working with library components see the tutorial in the [SharePoint Framework docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dev/spfx/library-component-tutorial?WT.mc_id=m365-00000-wmastyka).